# spring 3 MVC application start up and shutdown message

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC web application.
I would like to add start up and shutdown message. 
Where is the best place to write them? 

e.g - "webapp has started successfully!"

  - "webapp has shutdown successfully!"

I want to make sure the start up message show only after all the beans have been loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend `ContextLoaderListener` and then override the `contextInitialized()` and `contextDestroyed()` methods to write a log message or whatever you want.